# Disable transition effect field slideshow

Tags: nodes, media, entities

I have installed the [Field Slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) module.

I want to set the transition effect to none in manage displays (content type). 
How can this be done, I tried to set the interval to 0 but the slideshow keeps going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set "Transition speed" to 0 (zero) and it won't have any transition effect, just the direct change of image.

If you want to stop automatic changing of images, set "Timeout" to 0 (zero).